# What is a good learning source for programmer who wants to understand the infrastrucre of map based web map?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, mapserver, .net, asp.net

I want to to write a simple web app with a map (tile cache because of high resolution raster) that once a user clicks the map he can do some queries on it (as in search in polygon, radius, nearest...) on the TAB (Not Google Maps or Bing, but my own tab I've got from a GIS friend).

From the little I've read I've encountered many new Terms as: Web Map Server / Web Map Service / Tile cache / WFS etc...

I'm looking for free (open source probably) solution that I can learn and use in .Net. I know client side will be OpenLayers but still need some reading material that will make some sense (and explanation) on all these terms - architecture. I know there is GeoServer, SharpMap, MapServer, TileCache... just not sure what each does / used for...

Comment: Does it have to be .Net? Opensource and .Net is going to be difficult.

Comment: if you take GeoServer, or any other WMS / WFS capable map server, and OpenLayers you might be able to do everything in JavaScript and HTML without involving .NET. .NET is also a little inconvenient if you're running GeoServer as it's a java application, so you would probably need Apache/Tomcat and IIS running in parallel which seems a little redundant

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the answer. I'm a .Net developer and using the server side for wrapping the map with UI. I thought MapServer has .Net capabilities , or as an alternative (worst case scenario) is writing a Java based service and using a proxy to query it from .Net web app (the "view")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It deals more with the client side but try "Open Layers 2.10" by Erik Hazzard, it's a good book to start learning about webmapping with.

Comment: Thank you Banger , I've already acquired the book , but more important I want to understand the server side because I'm using custom made tabs and not BING or OSM layers.

Comment: When you say tab do you mean Mapinfo tab files?

Comment: that's more an area I am still learning about too but you could try open geo's white paper http://opengeo.org/publications/opengeo-architecture/ or Don Meltz has a blog about setting up his own map server, it's dated Jan 11 so a little while ago http://donmeltz.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/09/serving-maps-for-free/ but hopefully someone else who knows more about it will answer

Comment: Banger - Yes... I'm currently working with MapInfo professional tab files (and wor or mws workspace)